# how to extract only relevant data (up to an extent) based on a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a CUSTOMER table as like below, which is showing customer ordered product status
[image]

if there is no delivery status then the records should come as is (eg 101) ,If there is a delivery status we have to fetch the data till delivery, after delivery what ever the status might be it should be ignored.

the expected output will be like

[image]

How to write a sql query for this. Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Your results suggest that you think that the rows are in some sort of order.  But they are not, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: There is a date column based on that the status has been updated

Answer (score 1):

I would use;

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when status = 'Delivered' then date end) over (partition by cust_id, product) as min_delivered_date
      from t
     ) t
where min_delivered_date is null or
      date <= min_delivered_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag) FROM (
  SELECT *, 0 = COUNTIF(status = 'Delivered') OVER(delivered) flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW delivered AS (
    PARTITION BY cust_id, product 
    ORDER BY date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  )
)
WHERE flag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH delivered_at AS (
   SELECT CUST_ID, PRODUCT, STATUS, EVENT_TIME 
   FROM CUSTOMER
   WHERE STATUS = 'DELIVERED'
)

SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN DELIVERED
   ON DELIVERED.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
WHERE CUSTOMER.EVENT_TIME <= DELIVERED.EVENT_TIME
```

This would work if you had a timestamp, and is the safest choice, since new status may appear and you'd need to manually change your code. However, I'm assuming you don't have a timestamp for each status since you haven't pointed it out. So you can do something like:

```
   SELECT CUST_ID, PRODUCT, STATUS, 
        CASE WHEN STATUS = 'ORDERED' THEN 1
        CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SHIPPED' THEN 2
        CASE WHEN STATUS = 'IN PROGRESS' THEN 3
        CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DELIVERED' THEN 4
        ELSE 5 END AS ORDER_
   FROM CUSTOMER
)

SELECT *
FROM DELIVERED_ORDERED
WHERE ORDER_ < 4
```

Remember in this case to change your manual "ordering", since you have no cannonical definition of it from the columns you suggested.